# How to change size of plot in xgboost.plot_importance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, machine-learning, xgboost

```
xgboost.plot_importance(model, importance_type='gain')
```

I am not able to change size of this plot. I want to save this figure with proper size so that I can use it in pdf. I want similar like `figize`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It looks like `plot_importance` [return an `Axes` object](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.plot_importance)

```
ax = xgboost.plot_importance(...)
fig = ax.figure
fig.set_size_inches(h, w)
```

It also looks like you can pass an axes in

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(h, w))
xgboost.plot_importance(..., ax=ax)
```

Comment: ^ only the second option works for me as well. Regardless, thanks for the answer!

Comment: it is first width and then height btw :)

Answer (score 2):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 20))
xgb.plot_importance(bst, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```