# matplotlib:how to show all features(about 150 ones) clearly

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
from xgboost import plot_importance
from matplotlib import pyplot
plot_importance(model)
pyplot.show()
```

I got 150 features fitted into xgboost model and want to print out all the feature importance, however something mess printed out.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either only plot the most important features with

```
plot_importance(model, max_num_features=10)
```

or you could increase the plot size with

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(h, w))
xgboost.plot_importance(model, ax=ax)
```

as described in [How to change size of plot in xgboost.plot_importance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40664776/how-to-change-size-of-plot-in-xgboost-plot-importance).